# How to display null value when the record is present more than one time in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a result set like following:

```
1001    abcdefg
1001    dghfkdk
1001    lkjkjkl
1002    kkjhjkh
1003    iuoiuoi
1003    kjljklj
```

I want to display a null value in column 1 when it is more than once.

For ex:

```
1001    abcdefg
null    dghfkdk
null    lkjkjkl
1002    kkjhjkh
1003    iuoiuoi
null    kjljklj
```

Can some one help me in this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - a similar question but a completely inappropriate solution for Oracle. I can't believe other people have agreed with your "duplicate" suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use row_number:

```
select case when ranking = 1
        then id
        else null
        end as id
    , column_txt
from
(
    select id
        , column_txt
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by column_txt) as ranking
    from table
)t
```

Comment: This is really a display issue which ought to be handled by the client: if the client re-orders the result set this will look a right old mess. But it does answer the question the OP asked.