# display null value using rank functions in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking-functions

This is an extension of another question: [How to display null value when the record is present more than one time in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820262/how-to-display-null-value-when-the-record-is-present-more-than-one-time-in-oracl?noredirect=1#comment80595574_46820262)

I have a table set like following:

```
c_id    c_name     c_tax

1001    Element1   1 
1001    Element1   2
1001    Element2   1
1001    Element2   2
1002    Element3   null
1002    Element4   1
1002    Element4   2
```

I want to display `null` in the first `column(c_id)` if it is present more than once and yes or no in the 3rd `column(c_tax)` based on the following condition.

`Element1` has two taxes 1 and 2. So `Element1` should be displayed once and `c_tax` should be yes.
`Element3` has no tax so it should be displayed as `null`.

My output should look like following:

```
c_id    c_name     c_tax

1001    Element1   Yes 
null    Element2   Yes
1002    Element3   No
null    Element4   Yes
```

Comment: internal stackoverlow links should be pasted raw, rather than using link-formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by cid order by c_name) = 1 then cid end) as cid,
       c_name,
       (case when max(c_tax) is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end) as c_tax
from t
group by c_id, c_name
order by c_id, c_name;
```

Comment: Not only you understood correctly, your answer is perfect.Thanks much @Gordon Linoff